# Do ArcGIS clients that direct-connect to postgresql/postgis databases override configuration settings?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, postgresql, performance, arcgis-platform

I went in to modify some settings on a Postgresql database via the PGAdmin config editor and some of the settings don't have their default values and they are higher because they've been overridden (e.g.  `maintenance_work_mem` ).  I know PGAdmin will do this. And that I can do it manually in PSQL.

Do the ArcGIS clients ever override postgresql configuration settings?  And if so, what triggers it? Is it tool-based? Or when the software starts up? Or is Esri entirely hands-off?

Comment: Is the ESRI tool accessing the database as a user that even has rights to do that?

Comment: I think so, although I'm not entirely clear how to control access to the user context settings.  I created a new user, didn't assign any roles, and I could still override.